# How to overwrite an XML attribute value without reading the whole file in python

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

How do you overwrite a single attribute value when you are only reading one element at a time?

Specifically I am using `xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse()` to read each individual element. Then I am changing an attribute value.

What I need to do then is to overwrite the `original element` with the `changed element`.

Here is the example code so far:

```
osm_file = open(sample.osm, 'r+')

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(osm_file events=("start",)):

    # Making some changes
    elem.attrib['v'] = 'new_value'

    # Some how write the elem back to the XML file
```

The one thing that I can not do is to read the whole XML file into python because the file is too big.

Comment: That cannot possibly work. The XML handling is unaware that the data came from a file and so it cannot "write back" the changed value at the exact same position in the file. Even if it could: it is physically impossible to replace a text in a file with a shorter or longer text *without rewriting the entire file*. (The very only exceptions being "exactly the same length text" and "the data is at the very end".)

Comment: So then how do you work with large XML files? But that is something that I didn't think about.

Answer (score 1):

from usr2564301 as posted in the comments explained why this is not possible.

> That cannot possibly work. The XML handling is unaware that the data came from a file and so it cannot "write back" the changed value at the exact same position in the file. Even if it could: it is physically impossible to replace a text in a file with a shorter or longer text without rewriting the entire file. (The very only exceptions being "exactly the same length text" and "the data is at the very end".) – usr2564301

Answer (score 1):

iterparse still processes the whole tree.  You can't avoid that:

http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing

> Incremental Parsing # Note that iterparse still builds a tree, just
>   like parse, but you can safely rearrange or remove parts of the tree
>   while parsing. For example, to parse large files, you can get rid of
>   elements as soon as you’ve processed them:
>
> for event, elem in iterparse(source):
>       if elem.tag == "record":
>           ... process record elements ...
>           elem.clear()

**If your XML file is too big** to handle in your program then you need to consider another data storage format like a database.

Otherwise, you could do some file manipulation magic with the text file with sed and awk or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with huge files recently too, and couldn't fit them in memory. To fix this, I put together a simple package `bigread` (`pip install bigread`) that streams n lines of a file into RAM at once:

```
from bigread import Reader

# this will be the output file
with open('updated.xml', 'w') as out:
  # read the input file
  for i in Reader(file='input.xml', block_size=1):
    # check if this is a line you need to operate on
    if i.lstrip()[:5] == '<tag ':
      # replace the target attribute
      i = i.replace(' attr="cats" ', ' attr="dogs" ')
    # write the new line to disk
    out.write(i + '\n')
```